# Detect when search bar is pressed Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, searchbar

I am looking for a way to detect when a search bar is pressed or is focused in Ionic. As soon as it is clicked I want to open other page, this is the reason why I need to know when the search bar is pressed. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (ionFocus)

```
   <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search" (ionFocus)="focused($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Happy to help :)